# Excel gets corrupt and goes into read only mode

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

So I have an excel document that will just randomly break on me when opening it. I do have **Code 1** in the VBA ThisWorkbook section but it doesn't start until I enable macros after opening it.

The images attached are in the order that they appear to me. One note is that I do have hidden files revealed and I only see the "Ownership file" when I have it open. I am on a shared network but I do not have the privileges to view where it all is open.

My current work around is to save the file under a different name and then delete the old file and rename it.

After researching a bit, someone stated it might have had to do with sorting. But I added **Code 2** and I am still having the issue.

**Code 1**

```
Dim Result

Result = MsgBox("The Data in this document might be outdated. Would you like to refresh the Data Queries? This process could take a few minutes...", vbYesNo, "Data Query OutDated")
If Result = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox "Queries Will Refresh Upon Closing this window. Please wait"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SQLData").EnableCalculation = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FlowBreakDown").EnableCalculation = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Change_Background_Refresh False
    
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SQLData").EnableCalculation = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SQLData").EnableCalculation = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FlowBreakDown").EnableCalculation = False
    
    MsgBox "Refresh Complete"
    Call ResizeData
End Sub
```

**Code 2**

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
' Clear all Sort Fields prior to Save & Exit
For Each Sht In Application.Worksheets
    Sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Next Sht

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From the screenshots I assume you're on a PC. I'd try this utility which reveals what's locking your file/folder and also give you a chance to unlock: https://lockhunter.com

Comment: You wrote "I am on a shared network". Did you talk to the other participants on the network? Maybe they also have similar problems?

Comment: They are having the problem with my file but no others

Comment: Then go for lockhunter and reveal what's locking it!

Comment: I have more feasible options for you but I cannot write as an answer. As soon as I do the OP's are downvoting me and hide my answer. Strange.